# Rails: accessing records by ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I'm trying to access a record by simply referring to its ID, thus:

```
def article_by_id(a)
  @article = Article.where(:id => a)
end
```

And it refuses to work. Is there something I need to do in Rails to be able to use the ID in such a fashion? I've tried putting it in that model's `attr_accessible` list and nada.

And, yeah, the ID obviously exists when I edit that record itself despite it not showing up in the `schema.rb` file.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use
    Article.find()

Comment: Is there a difference replacing `where()` with `find()`? I do get a different error, though: `Unknown key: id`.

Comment: hmm...ar you doing this in your controller??   @article = Article.find(params[:id])

Comment: It's in the application helper. I'm using `@article` several times on the one page. For different things.

Comment: so when do you need to access this function?? can try to explain the flow or process you want to archive? here is the guide for activerecord http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Sure. And thanks for your help. I need to find three articles per this view, and I was using the above function to get them all in a loop in the view. I've changed what the database stores from an arbitrary integer to the article's ID (for a number of reasons) which is what broke this in the first place.

Comment: Ha, your initial suggestion fixed it. I had a formatting issue. For someone's reference: `Article.find(:id => a)` doesn't work, but `Article.find(a)` does. Cheers!